# React: how can I call a function when a component has loaded?

Tags: reactjs, loading, onload, onload-event

I am trying to use Google's [model-viewer web component](https://modelviewer.dev/) to display a model on my website. The documentation says the component has a 'loaded' property which is 'read only' and 'returns true if the load event has fired since the last src change'. I'm trying to use this property to call a function when the component has loaded but I don't think I'm accessing it correctly. Should I be using componentDidUpdate to check if this property has changed? Or is there a way of using onload()?

My code so far looks like this:

```
class App extends Component {

  isLoaded() {
    console.log("loaded!")
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <model-viewer
          src={require('..my model..')} 
          alt="A model"
          loading="eager"
          loaded={this.isLoaded}
         />
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: try in componentDidMount()

Comment: @bakar_dev how would I check if the component's loaded property is true in componentDidMount()? Does componentDidMount() only get called when all components have rendered?

Comment: yeah when a component mount..the componentDidMount() invokes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is `model-viewer` you used in this case **IS NOT** a React component. That mean it has neither react component behavior nor life cycle.

My solution is look for some other library as a wrapper like below:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-3d-model-viewer
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-model-viewer

Answer (score 26):

There are two solution for this depends on what kind of react logic you follow

1. Class based usually using keyword `class Welcome extends React.Component`
2. Using function based component and Hooks

**1. Class based on load**
For this solution you can use `componentDidMount` function

```
 class Welcome extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // call api or anything
    console.log("Component has been rendered");
  }
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello, World</h1>;
   }
 }
  
}
```

**2. Using function based component and Hooks**
The Effect Hook, useEffect, adds the ability to perform side effects from a function component. It serves the same purpose as componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, and componentWillUnmount in React classes [Ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html)

```
   import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

   export default function Welcome() {
     useEffect(() => {
        // call api or anything
        console.log("loaded");
     });
     return <h1>Hello, World</h1>;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

From the React docs:

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is mounted (inserted into the tree). Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request.

The docs for React lifecycle are [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for this:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    isLoaded: false
  }
  // use comonentDidMount lifecycle method
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ isLoaded: true });
    console.log("loaded!");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <model-viewer
          src={require('..my model..')} 
          alt="A model"
          loading="eager"
          loaded={this.state.isLoaded} // use this.state.isLoaded, not this.isLoaded
         />
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: sorry what does loaded={this.state.isLoaded} do? Does it set this.state.isLoaded to the value of loaded?

Comment: Oh sorry i misread your code. I thought you want to pass the isLoaded to your model-viewer, but you are actually passing a callback.

Comment: What is model-viewer? a component? web component? The parent component that you display here has nothing to do with the lifecycle of model-viewer, therefore you would have to share your code of model-viewer in order to understand the issue

Comment: model-viewer is a web component https://modelviewer.dev/

Comment: I'm confused about how I could access the 'loaded' property of the component or if there's a better way of calling a function when the component has loaded

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
In the documentation of "react-model-viewer" you can see under events, there is a load event that is triggered when the viewer is done loading. That should do it hopefully :)

```
 class App extends Component {

  isLoaded() {
    console.log("Loaded");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <model-viewer
          src={require('..my model..')} 
          alt="A model"
          loading="eager"
          load={this.isLoaded}
         />
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```